# Random Processes Mean Value and Variance(Poisson)

Tags: self-study, variance, mean, poisson-distribution

I've encountered with a random processes example and could not solve it properly. Could anyone help me?

"Suppose that **x**(t) is a Poisson process such that E{**x**(9)}=6. What is the mean and variance of **x**(8)?

We know that for Poisson process E{**x**(t)}=λt I thought since **x**(9)=6 λ=2/3. So, E{**x**(8)}= 16/3. But answer key says it is 24. I couldn't understand why?

Comment: This question needs the self-study tag.

Comment: I've added self-study tag

Comment: That is good.  It should help you get responses.